# Do Eucharistic miracles all have the same DNA?

Tags: transubstantiation

I have seen it claimed there are thousands of Eucharistic miracles, where what appears to us to be wafer and wine by their accidents, but in actuality are Jesus in substance, have their accidents also turned into what appears to us to be physical flesh and blood.

I have also read at least once such tissue was scientifically examined.  Since all the miraculously transformed objects are the same person, Jesus, they should all have the same DNA.  Has DNA ever been extracted from the tissue?  If so, has there been an attempt to scientifically examine multiple such tissue from independent miracles, and verify whether the DNA is all the same?

Comment: Probably. But, keeping in mind Deuteronomy 6:16, it is almost certain that whatever is so tested will test only as bread. It isn't God's Plan to give us irresistible evidence of His existence.

Comment: @Matthew I have seen it claimed that when scientifically examined Eucharistic miracles are found to be cardiac muscle and contain hemoglobin.  Very much no longer bread.  Of course, a skeptic could claim it's just a trick, and a priest swapped the bread for human tissue acquired from some person.  One way to refute the skeptic would be to show all the sampled miracles have the same DNA, even when they come from very different times and locations that would exceed the possibility to have the same human donor.

Comment:  I stand by my previous statement, but perhaps I am wrong. If such analyses are indeed genuine (and one suspects it would be hard to fake cardiac tissue), I would *expect* to always find the same DNA. Moreover, I would expect that DNA to be potentially interesting; at the least, it should be (genetically) ~2kyo.

Comment: Indeed, the DNA would be extremely interesting.  Such as, would it be identical to Mary's DNA and have no Y chromosome?  If so, what does that say about the role of DNA in bodily formation?  If not, who is the other DNA donor, or was the DNA created de novo?  Would the DNA be 'perfect', and if so, could it be used to fix other DNA?  Whole lot of questions!

Answer (score 2):

You're correct in saying that in Echaristic miracles, the "accidents also turned into what appears to us to be physical flesh and blood."

St. Thomas Aquinas discusses [Eucharistic miracles](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=6368) in [*Summa Theologica* III q. 76 a. 8](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/TP/TP076.html#TPQ76A8THEP1) "Whether Christ's body is truly there when flesh or a child appears miraculously in this sacrament?"; in Eucharistic miracles (co.),

> while the dimensions [of the Host or Blood] remain the same as before, there is a miraculous change wrought in the other [accidents](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=31615&randomterm=false), such as shape, color, and the rest, so that flesh, or blood, or a child, is seen.

Accidents inhere in a subject; but with transubstantiation, after consecration, God holds the accidents of bread and wine in existence despite their not inhering in a subject, which is now Christ's Body, Blood, soul, and divinity; this is one of the [three mysteries of transubstantiation](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/49011/1787). In Eucharistic miracles, the accidents are those of flesh and blood.

<sup>all but the 1<sup>st</sup> ¶ above from [this answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/91566/1787) to the question "[How can Catholics who adhere to Eucharistic Miracles claim the distinction between substance and accidents?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/91565/1787)"</sup>